# How to check HTTPS certificate on RESTful API?

Tags: dart, flutter

I use `HttpClient`.

I want to check client certificate, any ideas?

Can anyone help me?

I've built a RESTful API with Ruby On Rails, and now I would like to know whether the user's credentials received by POST are valid or not, using Devise.

Comment: sorry. i just want check https cert with flutter.